# JavaScript WebSocket Try's to open...then closes with no error

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm trying to vet out how WebSockets HTML5 and JavaScript work. I'm seeing no errors, but instead appears to just hang for a bit, and then call the closed callback. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I would think the onopen callback function to get called here.

```
            var socket;

            window.onload = function(argument) {

                try
                {

                    document.getElementById("console").innerHTML = "Opening WebSocket...";

                    socket = new WebSocket("ws://undergroundtechnetwork.com:8080/");

                    socket.onopen = function(){
                        document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += "<br />WebSocket opened.";
                    }

                    socket.onmessage = function(message){
                        document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += "<br />WebSocket recieved a message: " + message;
                    }

                    socket.onclose = function(){  

                         document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += "<br />WebSocket status: " + GetSocketStateName(socket.readyState);  
                    }

                    socket.onerror = function(e){
                    document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += "<br />WebSocket error message:<br />" + JSON.stringify(e);
                }


                }catch(e){
                    document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += "<br />Exception: " + e;
                }

            }

            function GetSocketStateName(state){
                var strSocketState;

                if(socket.readyState == 0){
                    strSocketState = "Connecting";
                }else if(socket.readyState == 1){
                    strSocketState = "Open";
                }else if(socket.readyState == 2){
                    strSocketState = "Closing";
                }else if(socket.readyState == 3){
                    strSocketState = "Closed";
                }

                return strSocketState;
            }
```

Update:

This is the error I'm getting in the on error. I don't get an error for 8080, but that's because it's not actual open ( its a hosting service server )

{"cancelBubble":false,"returnValue":true,"srcElement":{"binaryType":"blob","extensions":"","protocol":"","bufferedAmount":0,"readyState":0,"url":"ws://undergroundtechnetwork.com/","URL":"ws://undergroundtechnetwork.com/"},"defaultPrevented":false,"timeStamp":1369930726244,"cancelable":false,"bubbles":false,"eventPhase":2,"currentTarget":{"binaryType":"blob","extensions":"","protocol":"","bufferedAmount":0,"readyState":0,"url":"ws://undergroundtechnetwork.com/","URL":"ws://undergroundtechnetwork.com/"},"target":{"binaryType":"blob","extensions":"","protocol":"","bufferedAmount":0,"readyState":0,"url":"ws://undergroundtechnetwork.com/","URL":"ws://undergroundtechnetwork.com/"},"type":"error"}

Comment: The WebSocket protocol specification changed a few times since it was first proposed. It's possible that your server is using older version of the standard.

Comment: this ended up being the hosting company not supporting websockets unless I you pay for a static IP, and dedicated server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JavaScript seems to be OK. If you change

> ```
> socket = new WebSocket("ws://undergroundtechnetwork.com:8080/");
> ```

to let's say

> ```
> socket = new WebSocket("ws://echo.websocket.org");
> ```

it works fine. Try tweaking your WebSocket server instead.

Comment: Interesting. I will investigate the server side, and update my findings. Thank you.